# Как передать больше одного параметра в контроллер?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

У меня есть действие в контроллере:

```
public void CreateArticle([FromBody]string header, [FromBody]string content)
{
  // something code
}
```

И fetch-запрос:

```
fetch(
"/article", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    header: "Hello World!",
    content: 'Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")'
  })
});
```

При запуске проекта возникает ошибка:

> InvalidOperationException: Action 'ArticleController.CreateArticle()' has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body. Inspect the following parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to specify bound from query, 'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from route, and 'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body: string header, string content

Как передавать в действие контроллера больше одного параметра через тело fetch-запроса?

Comment: Может передать 1 параметр, но с 2 полями?

Comment: Суть в том, что HTTP-запрос может иметь только один `Request Body`. Поэтому атрибут `[FromBody]` можно применять только один раз для одного метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

// ...

[HttpPost]
public void CreateArticle([FromBody] Article article)
{
    // ...
}
```

```
fetch(
    "/article", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        header: "Hello World!",
        content: 'Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")'
    })
});
```

Comment: Да, работает. Но можно сделать это именно так, чтобы параметры передавались не через класс, а именно отдельно?

Comment: @eugene а зачем? чем не подходит `class`?

Comment: @eugene если же нужно передавать отдельно, то можно передавать из через `[FromQuery]` и указывать параметры не в body, а `/article?header=hello&content=world`